# Pegar conteúdo de uma página com PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Estou pegando todo o conteúdo de uma página com o código:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.teste.com.br';
$dadosSite = file_get_contents($url);
echo $dadosSite;
?>
```

Funciona normalmente e foi melhor do que usar *iframe*. Porém, no início da página que estou pegando, o conteúdo tem um *script* PHP que eu gostaria que fosse ignorado. Será que tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

---

Então cara, estou usando este script na verdade para pegar os dados da página de login do portal captivo do pfsense, foi a unica forma que encontrei de fazer a página de login do pfsense aparecer sendo chamada por uma url amigavel (pelo nome www.xxx.xx.xx). isso em uma rede interna. e no caso deu certo, pois a página onde está o script file_get_contents é um servidor ubuntu com dns. Assim a página de login do pfsense responde e o usuário faz login. (no pfsese para usar a página com url amigavel é necessário usar ssl, ou seja gastar com certificado e ainda se preocupar com dns para o certificado). O que ocorre é que para esta página do servidor ubuntu ser chamada assim que o usuário entra no wifi, ela precisa estar configurada no pfsese para que o pfsense direcione a página original do portal para o servidor ubuntu. Entende? Para que seja redirecionada, é necessário o script que falei que fica no começo da página, quando a página do pfsense redireciona para o servidor ubuntu, a página do servidor ubuntu onde está o script file_get_contents pega a página do pfsense novamente e fica sempre assim como um loop, ou seja, acredito que o script de redirecionamento que está no inicio da página do pfsense esteja sendo incluído também.

Script no inicio da página do pfsense.

```
<?php
require_once("globals.inc");

$request_uri = urldecode(str_replace("/index.php?redirurl=", "",  

$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));

$portal_redirurl = urldecode("$PORTAL_REDIRURL$");

if(!stristr(urldecode("$PORTAL_REDIRURL$"), $request_uri)) {

Header("Location: $PORTAL_REDIRURL$");

exit;
} ?>
```

Comment: Como assim um script PHP no início? Com esse código você estaria pegando apenas o código fonte da página; o PHP não deveria estar presente. Tem como melhorar essa informação e colocar um exemplo de que script seria este?